# Updating an object attribute Typescript React-Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to update an attribute. I'm new to typescipt (and react/react-native/javascript etc.) so please be patient. Here is an attempt to try to recreate my issue:

```
export default function App() {
  const [schedule, setSchedule] = useState({
    id: 12409,
    name: 'Schedule1',
    start: 9,
    end: 10
  })
  const [startHour, setStartHour] = useState({
    start: 7
  })
  const [endHour, setEndHour] = useState({
    end: 11
  })
  const [scheduleFinal, setFinal] = useState(schedule)
  submitPress(() => {
      setFinal([...schedule], start, start: startHour.start)
    };
    return ( <
      View >
      <
      Button title = "Change Start and End"
      onPress = {
        submitPress
      }
      /> <
      Text > New start: {
        scheduleFinal.start
      }
      New End: {
        scheduleFinal.end
      } < /Text> <
      /View>
    );
  }
```

I am trying to replace the attributes:

start
end

in the schedule object with the attributes held in startHour and endHour states. I've tried various combinations of logic that haven't worked. I'm not sure if the method that I have here will work at all, but at least people should be able to tell what I am after.

Comment: Something like `setFinal({...schedule, start: startHour, end: endHour})`

Comment: Why is `submitPress` being randomly invoked?

Comment: @Urmzd , not sure what you mean by randomly invoked, it is called when the button is pressed.

Comment: @Nick that ended up being the ticket.

Comment: @corgiraptor `submitPress` is not binded to any namespace. It's being reinvoked every single render... Even if it's out the scope of `App`, the only place it should exist is `Button < onPress`.

Answer (score 0):

With Nick's help I came up with the solution. Hopefully this will help others if they run into this issue. Please note I had to add a couple other hooks (useRef and useEffect) in order to render the text properly:

```
export default function App() {
  const [schedule, setSchedule] = useState({
    id: 12409,
    name: 'Schedule1',
    start: 9,
    end: 10
  })
  const [startHour, setStartHour] = useState({
    start: 7
  })
  const [endHour, setEndHour] = useState({
    end: 11
  })
  const [scheduleFinal, setFinal] = useState(schedule)
  const count = useRef(0);

  submitPress(() => {
      setFinal({...schedule,  start: startHour.start,end:endHour.end})
      count.current = count.current + 1;
    };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (count.current > 0) {
      alert(schedulefinal.start);
    }
  }, [schedulefinal]);
    return ( <
      View >
      <
      Button title = "Change Start and End"
      onPress = {
        submitPress
      }
      /> <
      Text > New start: {
        scheduleFinal.start
      }
      New End: {
        scheduleFinal.end
      } < /Text> <
      /View>
    );
  }
```